# Removing item from ICollectionView

Tags: c#, icollectionview

How can I remove item from ICollectionView in c#?

```
Dictionary<int, String> entityDict;
public ICollectionView DictView { get; set; }
dictView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(entityDict.Values);
dictView.//No remove method
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't because it's a **view** of a collection. You need to remove the item from the underlying collection or use a filter. If you are interested in filtering then this question provides further information and links: [WPF's ICollectionView.filter with large sets of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851545/wpfs-icollectionview-filter-with-large-sets-of-data)

Answer (score 1):

What ChrisWue says, is correct.
You could check the [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.filter.aspx) property of ICollectionView; perhaps it suits your needs.