# Databound ListView Multi-Select and Filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a list of of databound items.

I have a textbox that filters them on the fly by binding their visibility to whether or not the description contains the typed text. This also is bound to the 'focusable' property to remove selected items that are not visible because of the filter.

The DataTrigger for the ListBoxItems:

```
            <DataTrigger Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource filterToBoolean}">
                        <Binding Path="Description" />
                        <Binding ElementName="txtFilter" Path="Text" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
```

My problem shows up in the following scenario. Say we have three items (Joe, Bob, Jacob).

If we type 'J' in the filter and then select 'Joe' and Shift+Click 'Jacob' there will be three items selected (all of them) even though 'Bob' is not visible. The same applies if all three were selected before the filter was applied.

I have found an example here that attempts to fix this, but, it doesn't completely work. It'll apply if the items are selected before the filter is applied, but, if selected afterwards the same problem arises.

Thanks in advance for any help here.

Comment: you should use [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) (see remarks).  As well, google "WPF ListView filter"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListView` will create a `ListViewItem` for each object in your collection. Just because the visibility is set to hidden doesn't mean that the item is not in the listview. When you Shift-Select items it selects all items between the two - which includes "Bob" (visible or not).

For proper collection filtering you should use the `Filter` attribute of the `CollectionViewSource`. A sample of how it can be done is the accepted answer in this question: [Trigger Filter on CollectionViewSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466917/trigger-filter-on-collectionviewsource)

**Edit**

There are many reasons why your filtering might be slow. This question has some suggestion for things you can check: [WPF's ICollectionView.filter with large sets of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851545/wpfs-icollectionview-filter-with-large-sets-of-data)

If that does not help then maybe ask another question on SO (you should provide the code of how you do the filtering and listview databinding).

Comment: I tried the filter previously and it ended up being very slow. Binding it the way I did would make the filtering essentially instant whereas the 'filter' would take 10-15 seconds for each letter typed. - I am going to try it again and see if I can get it to work more quickly. Thanks.

Comment: As expected, it works, but is quite slow. Maybe I am doing something else wrong? I feel like it's slow because it is recreating each item from the datatemplate, were the visibility changes would leave all of them created, in memory, and just change some properties. Any help?